# Load the data before template render in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I am using **Angular 6** and using one way binding.

My code in component is given below.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.profile.getUser(1).subscribe((data) => {
  this.userData = this.compiler.constructUserData(data);
 });
}
```

userData has one object and it has properties. I am trying to bind its data in HTML as shown below

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem">
          <span matLine>
            <span>First Name: </span>
            <span> {{userData?.first_name}}</span>
          </span>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item role="listitem">
          <span matLine>
            <span>Last Name: </span>
            <span> {{userData?.last_name}} </span>
          </span>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item role="listitem">
          <span matLine>
            <span>Email: </span>
            <span> {{userData?.email}} </span>
          </span>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item role="listitem">
          <span matLine>
            <span>Mobile: </span>
            <span> {{userData.mobile_no}} </span>
          </span>
        </mat-list-item>
```

here I have used `?` after `userData` variable. But when I write ? with last item as well

e.g. `mobile_no` it doesn't show any of the data (first_name, last_name, email or mobile_no) on the web. But if I remove `?` from last item or any of the item. Data shows up but in console of web page.

Errors shows up as shown below.

[image: Error description]

Comment: please share your `json`. what data you are getting from service and also provide a minimal small example in `stackblitz.com`, if possible.

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(this.compiler.constructUserData(data))` in your `ngOnInit` ?

Comment: Data is being fetched from api like {"first_name": "", "last_name": "", "email": "", "mobile_no": ""}

Comment: I am aware of your intention Umair, but I strongly believe the input you're getting from `this.compiler.constructUserData(data)` is not exactly what you're expecting.

Comment: @Stavm when I add break point at this line, execute it data shows up. But when it doesn't get stopped with break point. Data doesn't shows up.

Comment: write `debugger;` just before `this.userData = this.compiler.constructUserData(data);` and keep chrome dev tools open. it'll stop.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could share a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue. There could be several issues in there.  What is `compiler` in `this.compiler.constructUserData(data);` What's the definition of that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're subscribing to the `Observable` and not placing a `?` in the template, make sure to initialize the `this.userData` with an empty Object initially.

Something like this:

```
userData = {};
```

---

I'd recommend you to rather use the `async` pipe in the template and not subscribe to the Observable. Assuming that you'll get the `userData` as an Object containing `email`, `first_name`, etc. in your `userData` Object, this would look something like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

userData$;

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.userData$ = this.profile.getUser(1).pipe(
    map(data => {
      return this.compiler.constructUserData(data);
    })
  );
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="userData$ | async as userData">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">
    <span matLine>
            <span>First Name: </span>
    <span> {{userData.first_name}}</span>
    </span>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">
    <span matLine>
            <span>Last Name: </span>
    <span> {{userData.last_name}} </span>
    </span>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">
    <span matLine>
            <span>Email: </span>
    <span> {{userData.email}} </span>
    </span>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">
    <span matLine>
            <span>Mobile: </span>
    <span> {{userData.mobile_no}} </span>
    </span>
  </mat-list-item>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-data-async?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: pipe, map not working. Here is our getUser function in service
  getUser(id) {
    return this.http.get(`${ConstantService.apiRoutes.user}/${id}`);
  }

Comment: @UmairJameel, I've updated my answer with a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-data-async?file=src/app/app.component.html)** that might help you understand what I'm suggesting.