# Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have Angular form. Its form with basic person data with 2 nested elements and i cant set validators for nested item.
JSON witch i want get its something like this :

```
{
"FirstName": "Tom",
"LastName":"Hanks",
"User": {
     "Username": "TestAdres",
     "EMail": "email@address.com"
},
"Address": {
     "City": "Miami",
     "Street": "Bugatti",
     "ZipCode": "123-123",
     "HouseNumber" : "5b"
}
```

}

My ngInit look like this :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.clientForm = new FormGroup({  
    firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    user: new FormGroup({      
      email:  new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])
      }),
    address: new FormGroup({       
      city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      street:  new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      houseNumber:  new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      zipCode:  new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      })
    });
  this.getClient();
}
```

and HTML is here :

```html
<h2>edit client</h2>
<form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" formGroupName="user">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.minlength">Email must be at least 6 characters</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" formGroupName="address">
        <h3>Adres:</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">Miejscowosc</label>
            <input type="city" formControlName="city" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.city.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.city.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.city.errors.required">City is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="street">Ulica</label>
            <input type="street" formControlName="street" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.street.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.street.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.street.errors.required">Street is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="houseNumber">Nr domu</label>
            <input type="houseNumber" formControlName="houseNumber" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.houseNumber.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.houseNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.houseNumber.errors.required">houseNumber is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="zipCode">Kod pocztowy</label>
            <input type="zipCode" formControlName="zipCode" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.zipCode.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.zipCode.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.zipCode.errors.required">Zip code is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            Apply
        </button>
        <button type="button" (click)="generatePass()" [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-link">
            <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            Generate new password
        </button>
        <a routerLink="" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
    </div>
   
</form>
```

I have problem with validations. Nested controls don't have "errors" property. For Last Name and First name my code works fine. 
I work 3 days with this problem and i dont have ideas how i can make it.

THANKS !

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz reproducing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined` says that `address` and `user` properties has been not initialized before you used them in `[ngClass]` statement.

There is few possible solutions:

1. You can try to move `ngOnInit` to component constructor.
2. Use `?.` syntax in `[ngClass]` statements [check docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)
3. Prepare empty `f` object in constructor with all fields empty and fill them up later. Smilar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994009)

Answer (score 1):

Sample of resolve my problem is here : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xaercd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
I must refer to element this way :

```html
<div *ngIf="clientForm.get('user').get('email').errors?.required">Email is required</div>
```

Thanks guys for help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing the following.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="zipCode">Kod pocztowy</label>
            <input type="zipCode" formControlName="zipCode" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.get('address.zipCode).hasErrors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.get('address.zipCode).hasErrors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="form.get('address.zipCode').hasError('required')">Zip code is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```