# Cannot read property 'knowas' of undefined angular wite using interface Users

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm getting data from my server using service in angular this my userservice code.

```
GetUser(id: any): Observable<User>
{
  const header = new HttpHeaders();
  header.append('content-type', 'application/json');
  return this.httpclient.get<User>(this.baseurl + '/' + id, {headers: header});
}
```

model user

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    knowas: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    photourl: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    introduction?: string;
    lookingFor?: string;
    photos?: Photo[];
}
```

and i use this code from my memberdetialcomponent.ts and this my code.

```
export class MemberDetialComponent implements OnInit {
user: User;
id: number;
  constructor(private userservice: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaduser();
    console.log(this.user);
  }
  // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  loaduser()
  {
    this.userservice.GetUser(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(
      (users: User) =>
      {
        this.user = users;
       // console.log(this.user);
      }, ( error) =>
      {
       this.alertify.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

when use console.log(this.user); i get information but use it in my html it say can't read your property knowAs.
this my html code in angular

```
<h6>
  {{user.knowas}}
</h6>
```

can anybody help me to solve this? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load the data before template render in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993922/load-the-data-before-template-render-in-angular)

Comment: no it didn't work